# What does "+resetStandardUserDefaults" actually do?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Have tried to use "+resetStandardUserDefaults" of the NSUserDefaults class to reset the default values to their "factory" settings.  It turns out to be not the appropriate method to use.  Find out from some archived discussions in SO that we should use the instance method "removeObjectForKey" to remove the user's settings instead.

But am just curious and hope that someone could explain the actual usage of "+resetStandardUserDefaults".  Have read the reference web manual about this.  But it is very brief and I don't seem to get what it really means ...

Comment: I think it's a **total mystery** and nobody really knows.  There is great confusing between "resetting" during **this launch** and "resetting" "the user's preferences" (as you'd normally think of that as a user).

Comment: @Joe Blow, you are right, the factory defaults doesn't seem to be changed by "+resetStandardUserDefaults" as I have just added a button to the sample code to test call the class method.  Wonder if anyone has contacted Apple on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere (usually in the app delegate +initialize) you declare the standard user defaults (preferences of your app at the first launch).
+resetStandardUserDefaults makes your app mean it's the first launch and uses the user defaults the way you declared them in the app delegate.

**THE ABOVE IS THE WRONG ANSWER**

As [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/resetStandardUserDefaults) says, it:

*Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object and releases it from memory*

The *reset* portion refers to the fact that the *standardUserDefaults* object **in memory** is destroyed, so you get a fresh one from the file system next time you use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` but it has nothing to do with any *first launch* behaviour.

The call would make sense if it was renamed *flushDefaultsToDisk* or similar. It is the most misleadingly-named part of iOS SDK I've seen so far.

(I corrected this in-place as this rates quite highly on searches and didn't want to put the correction in a comment which someone might not read.)

Comment: From the sample tutorial code am following, it did not have the +resetStandardUserDefaults call when starting up the user default system.  Is there some special circumstances that we need to use the "+reset ..." call?

Comment: do you mean that after the +resetStandardUserDefaults call, the user defaults up to that point become the factory defaults?

Comment: Exactly. You usually don't use +resetStandardUserDefaults. You can declare the factory defaults. When the user want to he can change the settings. They aren't the factory settings anymore. But when you want to you can set the custom settings to the factory settings.

Comment: we may need to look into the matter a bit more.  As Joe Blow have mentioned, there are some confusion among developers about the usage of +resetStandardUserDefaults.  And I have tested it again and it doesn't seem to have any effect on the factory defaults.